# CloudLinux 7.8 error installing postgresql 11 Requires: llvm-toolset-7-clang >= 4.0.1

Tags: postgresql, centos

I've got a CloudLinux 7.8 (based on CentOS 7) machine and I'm trying to install postgresql11-devel onto the system and it fails due to 'llvm-toolset-7-clang >= 4.0.1'.

Here is the full error

```
[map7@ded94686 testapp]$ sudo yum install postgresql11 postgresql11-devel postgresql11-libs postgresql11-server
[sudo] password for map7: 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, rhnplugin, universal-hooks
This system is receiving updates from CLN.
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * EA4: 101.0.120.94
 * cpanel-addons-production-feed: 101.0.120.94
 * cpanel-plugins: 101.0.120.94
 * cloudlinux-x86_64-server-7: cl.mirror.serversaustralia.com.au
 * epel: fedora.mirror.serversaustralia.com.au
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package postgresql11.x86_64 0:11.8-1PGDG.rhel7 will be installed
---> Package postgresql11-devel.x86_64 0:11.8-1PGDG.rhel7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: llvm5.0-devel >= 5.0 for package: postgresql11-devel-11.8-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: llvm-toolset-7-clang >= 4.0.1 for package: postgresql11-devel-11.8-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libicu-devel for package: postgresql11-devel-11.8-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64
---> Package postgresql11-libs.x86_64 0:11.8-1PGDG.rhel7 will be installed
---> Package postgresql11-server.x86_64 0:11.8-1PGDG.rhel7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libicu-devel.x86_64 0:50.2-4.el7_7 will be installed
---> Package llvm5.0-devel.x86_64 0:5.0.1-7.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: llvm5.0(x86-64) = 5.0.1-7.el7 for package: llvm5.0-devel-5.0.1-7.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libedit-devel for package: llvm5.0-devel-5.0.1-7.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libLLVM-5.0.so()(64bit) for package: llvm5.0-devel-5.0.1-7.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libLTO.so.5()(64bit) for package: llvm5.0-devel-5.0.1-7.el7.x86_64
---> Package postgresql11-devel.x86_64 0:11.8-1PGDG.rhel7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: llvm-toolset-7-clang >= 4.0.1 for package: postgresql11-devel-11.8-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libedit-devel.x86_64 0:3.0-12.20121213cvs.el7 will be installed
---> Package llvm5.0.x86_64 0:5.0.1-7.el7 will be installed
---> Package llvm5.0-libs.x86_64 0:5.0.1-7.el7 will be installed
---> Package postgresql11-devel.x86_64 0:11.8-1PGDG.rhel7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: llvm-toolset-7-clang >= 4.0.1 for package: postgresql11-devel-11.8-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: postgresql11-devel-11.8-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64 (pgdg11)
           Requires: llvm-toolset-7-clang >= 4.0.1
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I've tried installing the latest llvm-toolset-6.0 but it cannot find it.

```
[map7@ded94686 testapp]$ sudo yum install llvm-toolset-6.0
[sudo] password for map7: 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, rhnplugin, universal-hooks
This system is receiving updates from CLN.
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * EA4: 101.0.120.94
 * cpanel-addons-production-feed: 101.0.120.94
 * cpanel-plugins: 101.0.120.94
 * cloudlinux-x86_64-server-7: cl.mirror.serversaustralia.com.au
 * epel: fedora.mirror.serversaustralia.com.au
No package llvm-toolset-6.0 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

**Update**

Tried just installing the libpqxx-devel package but get the same error

**Update**

Unfortunately this machine has CPanel on it, which could be getting in the way.

**Update**

Here is the list of repository files it uses

```
$ ls -al /etc/yum.repos.d
total 124
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root  4096 May 20 22:14 .
drwxr-xr-x. 111 root root 16384 May 21 10:40 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root root   329 Apr 23 20:46 centos-extras.repo
-rw-r--r--    1 root root   755 Apr 16 02:58 cloudlinux-ea4-experimental.repo
-rw-r--r--    1 root root   660 Apr 16 02:58 cloudlinux-ea4.repo
-rw-r--r--    1 root root  7636 Apr 16 02:58 cloudlinux-ea4-rollout.repo
-rw-r--r--    1 root root   734 Apr 16 02:58 cloudlinux-ea4-testing.repo
-rw-r--r--    1 root root   232 Apr 23 20:46 cloudlinux-imunify360.repo
-rw-r--r--    1 root root  2939 May 20 14:08 cloudlinux.repo
-rw-r--r--    1 root root  2937 May 20 14:08 cloudlinux.repo~
-rw-r--r--    1 root root  7474 Apr 23 20:46 cloudlinux-rollout.repo
-rw-r--r--    1 root root   257 May 19 22:17 cPAddons.repo
-rw-------    1 root root   241 May 20 22:14 cpanel-plugins.repo
-rw-r--r--    1 root root   234 May 18 12:53 dell-system-update_os_dependent.repo
-rw-r--r--    1 root root   263 May 18 12:53 dell-system-update_os_independent.repo
-rw-r--r--    1 root root   204 Aug  8  2015 EA4.repo
-rw-r--r--    1 root root  1050 Sep 18  2019 epel.repo
-rw-r--r--    1 root root  1149 Sep 18  2019 epel-testing.repo
-rw-r--r--    1 root root   120 May 15 00:45 kernelcare.repo
-rw-r--r--    1 root root  1838 Apr 27  2017 mysql-community.repo
-rw-r--r--    1 root root  1885 Apr 27  2017 mysql-community-source.repo
-rw-r--r--    1 root root   474 Apr 25  2018 nodesource-el7.repo
-rw-r--r--    1 root root  1331 May 18 12:50 puppetlabs.repo
-rw-r--r--    1 root root   130 May 20 10:06 yarn.repo
-rw-r--r--    1 root root   229 May 18 12:56 Zabbix_7_x86_64.repo
-rw-r--r--    1 root root   258 May 18 12:56 Zabbix_nonsupported_7_x86_64.repo
```

Adding the centos SCL doesn't work, but maybe there is something similar for cloudlinux, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 17):

Like [Rishitha Minol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4881848/rishitha-minol) said, but specific to CentOS:

```
yum install centos-release-scl-rh
```

then update or install as needed.

Found [here](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-sclo-rh-x86_64/llvm-toolset-7-clang-4.0.1-1.el7.x86_64.rpm.html).

Comment: Running `yum update` gave me the same error message as described.  This worked on my CentOS 7 server.

Answer (score 10):

```
sudo yum install centos-release-scl
```

And make

```
sudo yum install postgresql11 postgresql11-devel postgresql11-libs postgresql11-server
```

References can be found in [this](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/llvm-toolset-7.0/) link.

Comment: Tried that and I get 'No package centos-release-scl available.'

Comment: Sorry it's CloudLinux 7.8 which is based on CentOS 7, which would be why I cannot install the SCL repo

Answer (score 7):

`llvm5.0-devel` is part of [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL)

```
sudo yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

You need both EPEL and SCL, so also

```
sudo yum install centos-release-scl
```

You'd have to ask the CentOS / Red Hat people why they decided to scatter things around like this.

Comment: I think your answer is correct.  But I take issue with the last line.  It's not really RedHat's fault, per se, other than their staunch reluctance to update components with the _default_ packages.  That's what SCL is for (newer versions of llvm clang, for example), and that's kind of what epel helps to resolve, though epel is a bit of a band aid.  You're not running CentOS or RHEL if you want the latest packages just released.  That's part of the "contract" you "sign" when using CentOS/RHEL (agree to have stable packages, and never update major (or minor) versions of packages).

Comment: this worked for me finally ||
sudo yum install epel-release ||
after that I could do ->  sudo yum install llvm5.0-devel

Answer (score 2):

**Edited**
Install the repository RPM for PostgreSQL version 9.5 ~13(current), this is not an answer to the question:

```
yum install -y https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm
```

install the extra repositories.

To install Postgresql-11 on CentOS7, there are some packages are required to install, and during install PostgreSQL by "yum install postgresql11* "those requirements will be download from the available repo.

```
yum install -y epel-release
```

This will also resolve this problem if you are using CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)

> Error: Package: postgresql11-devel-11.8-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64 (pgdg11)
> Requires: llvm-toolset-7-clang >= **5.0**

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

I had 2 errors ->

1. missing llvm-toolset
2. missing llvm5.0-devel

toolset solution is up there but to install llvm5.0-devel first I had to install

```
sudo yum install epel-release
```

Then this worked

```
sudo yum install llvm5.0-devel
```

Comment: Yeah not seeing this one work for me. :/